# How to get List array inside multiple list array in android using pojo class

Tags: android, arraylist, retrofit2, pojo

I have getting follwing response from the api
and i have to get this reponse like this :

```
@SerializedName("AllQuestions")
public List<AllQuestions> AllQuestions;
```

I have got the AllQuestion array but now how to get inside the multiple list array in pojo class

```
"AllQuestions": [
                                        [
                                            {
                                                "QuestionID": "1",
                                                    "QuestionText": "What was the name of your elementary/primary school?"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "QuestionID": "2",
                                                    "QuestionText": "What was your childhood nickname?"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            {
                                                "QuestionID": "11",
                                                    "QuestionText": "What was your favorite sport in high school?"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "QuestionID": "12",
                                                    "QuestionText": "What was the name of the hospital where you  born?"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            {
                                                "QuestionID": "21",
                                                    "QuestionText": "Where were you when you had your first kiss?"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "QuestionID": "22",
                                                    "QuestionText": "What are the last 4 digits of your driving license?"
                                            },
                                        ]
                                    ]
```

AllQuestion.java (POJO Class)

```
@SerializedName("QuestionID")
public String QuestionID;

@SerializedName("QuestionText")
public String QuestionText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Visit http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Step 2: Copy your response and paste it there and enter package and class name

Step 3: Select target language as Java

Step 4: Mark source type to Json

Step 5: Mark annotation style to Gson

Step 6: Preview it

Step 7: Copy those classes to your app package

Comment: yep that's one good approach, but for null values it just creates Object class instances , make sure to modify them manually.

Answer (score 0):

**Question.java**

```
public class Question {

@SerializedName("QuestionID")
public String QuestionID;

@SerializedName("QuestionText")
public String QuestionText;
}
```

**AllQuestion.java**

```
public class AllQuestion{
  public List<Question> questions; // no need of serialization as inner array 
    doesn't have any keys
}
```

Then use below

```
@SerializedName("AllQuestions")
public List<AllQuestions> AllQuestions;
```